# Disassemble ikea sofa - screws issue

Tags: screws

Does anyone know how to eject these types of screws from ikea sofas? I can loosen the screw, but not the hook.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Why would you try to disassemble anything from IKEA? Putting it together in the first place is a major accomplishment, I would not tempt fate.

Answer (score 2):

A pair of nuts matching the existing thread can be threaded on the free end of the bolt. Use a pair of wrenches to tighten the nuts securely against each other. After loosening the nut against the frame, you can hammer against the paired nuts with a smaller risk to the bolt. If the bolt has to be turned, the paired nuts will provide a surface on which the wrench can act.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a carriage bolt. If you search for "remove carriage bolt" you get a lot of hits like this one: http://www.prettyhandygirl.com/how-to-remove-a-rusted-carriage-bolt/

Cutting a slot in the bolt for a flathead screwdriver is one option. You can also cut flats on either side of the bolt to grab it with a wrench. A less invasive option would be to rough up the surface, you can then press in hard with something grippy and it may hold the bolt enough to get the nut off. Finally, cutting it off is also an option.

Once you get this out, consider replacing it with a proper bolt and nut for later removal. If soft materials, like a cushion, will be in contact with the head of the carriage bolt choose a bolt with as few sharp corners as practical. A slotted, hex, Robertson, or Torx drive should all be safe enough and not damage a soft material. You can also get rounded plastic caps for to put over the exposed bolt head as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason for selecting the carriage bolt is to minimize the space it takes up to protect the cushion.

Comment: @ratchetfreak OH I was not aware that cavity was for a cushion. Edit coming....

Answer (score 0):

Use a vice grip on the threads to stop the bolt from turning and then a wrench to turn the nut. This will damage the threads a bit so the final bit will be harder to get off. You can whack the bolt out a bit and then grip on the other side to continue.

Comment: Padding the threads with a bit of cardboard can prevent that damage while still providing enough grip.

Comment: Use the vice grips on the head end of the bolt, not the thread, and you won't have this problem. Its harder to get a grip since you're grabbing 1/16" or so of the edge of the head, but it doesn't mangle the threads.